# onSuccess and onError are not working in newest version of React-Query?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query, trpc

Errors show up in **onSuccess** and **onError** functions. Did some research and turns out these functions are depcrecated in newest version of React-Query.

```js
"use client"

import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import { trpc } from '../_trpc/client'
import { Loader2 } from 'lucide-react'

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const origin = searchParams.get('origin')

  trpc.authCallback.useQuery(undefined, {
    onSuccess: ({ success }) => {
      if (success) {
        // user is synced to db
        router.push(origin ? `/${origin}` : '/dashboard')
      }
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      if (err.data?.code === 'UNAUTHORIZED') {
        router.push('/sign-in')
      }
    },
    retry: true,
    retryDelay: 500,
  })

  return (
    <div className='w-full mt-24 flex justify-center'>
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center gap-2'>
        <Loader2 className='h-8 w-8 animate-spin text-zinc-800' />
        <h3 className='font-semibold text-xl'>
          Setting up your account...
        </h3>
        <p>You will be redirected automatically.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Tried some to use some answers from similar problems but they were written in a completely different format and didnt work/i didnt know how to apply them. This is from a YT tutorial btw and im completely new to web dev so im pretty lost here. Any workaround to this?